# what is the type of '0 as opposed to 'b0 in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

for expressions like

```
wire matched2 = (a == '0);
wire matched1 = (a == 'b0);
```

Do '0 and 'b0 have different types?

Answer (score 5):

'b0 -- is an unsized literal and its width is 32-bits (32'b0). So, there are 32-bits of zeros.

'0 -- is a one-bit unsized constant and is a system verilog syntax used to make sure that there are as many zeros as needed in the context of an expression.

For practical reasons these two would behave the same just because they are unsigned zeros.

However there will be a big difference between `'b1` and `'1`; The former will end up being a 32-bit '1' (32'b1), whether the latter will fill **all** its bits with 1 (111111...).

Answer (score 2):

`'b0` is equivalent to writing `32'b0` with one exception—it's illegal to use an implicitly sized literal as an operand inside a concatenation, like `{1,'b0}`. This is because people mistakenly think they are writing 2'b10.

However you can use `{'1,'0}` because in a self-determined context `'0` is always a single bit. In an expression context, `'0` and `'1` will fill 0's or 1's the the size of the context it's in.

In your example, `'0` is in a context determined by the equality `==` operator and the smaller width operand width will be sized to the larger operand.

Comment: What about 0, is that '0 or 1'b0?

Comment: 0, 'b0 'h0 are all equivalent to 32'b0 or 32'h0 with the one noted exception.